# Jquery error: Object expected

Tags: jquery

This is my code in aspx page

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="//Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divGridView table tbody tr").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).addClass("highlightRow");
        }).mouseout(function () { $(this).removeClass('highlightRow'); })
    });       
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="divGridView">
 <asp:GridView ID="gvOpenSII" runat="server">
 </asp:GridView>
```

When I run this code i get error: "Jquery runtime error: object expected".

I want to highlight the particular row in gridview on mouse hover.

Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would double check the script tag src attribute. Try

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

or maybe

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Comment: code looks ok to me - could try a cdn to confirm that you can hit jquery - assuming you can get onto the url from your box http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js. I would check the location of the script. Does a really simple jquery sample run i.e. alert($('body')); Or you could use the google cdn as this SO gives details. Here it was the script tag that was in error

Comment: Thank you so much..This was url issue only. I tried pick url option in visual studio and my new script tag look like **<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what html that is generating, but if it's not finding the element you're targeting that might cause the problem.

Try this instead, you'll have to adjust it a bit to suit your code, but it should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/will/8e2RQ/

```
$(function(){
    $('table tr').bind('mouseenter mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('highlightRow');
    });
});
```